# How does the order() function in R work for character vectors?

Tags: r

Here my R code:

```
>vec <- c("bbb","zzz","aaa")  
>order(vec)  
[1] 3 1 2  
>vec[order(vec)]  
[1] "aaa" "bbb" "zzz"
```

An order of 3,1,2 should have resulted in "zzz" "aaa" "bbb". However I get "aaa" "bbb" "ccc". This is the correct order, just does not match with what the order() returned originally

Comment: Order returns the indices to get the sorted order. The third one ("aaa") goes first, so `3` is the first index. Compare to `rank()`.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense

Comment: It's a pity that duplicate suffers from showing an example vector of length 50 when one of length 4 or 5 would do the job.